# How to make NelmioApiDocBundle work with Symfony's FormType

Tags: php, symfony, single-page-application, fosrestbundle, nelmioapidocbundle

After working a while now with FOSRestBundle, I feel like I'm missing something.
In my opinion FOSRestBundle and Symfony's FormType - are kinda similar.
Both are your "data broker". Each have its own thing, but eventually they are similar.

Nowadays, everyone migrates towards Single-Page-Applications. Which means that everyone are trying to use their existing FormType(s) and build an API using FOSRestBundle. But they cannot document it easily. NelmioApiDocBundle doesn't work with FormType. Or Am I missing something?

So my question is: Is it possible to "tell" NelmioApiDocBundle to use a FormType for it's documentation (describe required data)?

**Seems like** there is a [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39970233/nelmio-api-doc-bundle-not-render-input-type) for this issue,
But it **doesn't work**.

Controller annotation:

```
@ApiDoc(
    resource=true,
    description="Register a new User",
    views = {"v1"},
    input="register_form"
)
```

FormType:

```
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => User::class,
        'csrf_protection'   => false,
        'allow_extra_fields'   => true,
    ));
}

public function getBlockPrefix()
{
    return 'register_form';
}

public function getName()
{
    return 'register_form';
}
```

service.yml:

```
register_form:
    class: AppBundle\Form\API\UserRegisterType
    tags:
        - { name: form.type, alias: register_form }
```

Please advise,
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `input="register_form"` use `input=“AppBundle\Form\API\UserRegisterType”`

Comment: I have it just like that and it works, try removing `resource=true,`, also what version of nelmioapidoc are you on? and how does your endpoint look in the documentation, is the parameters just blank?

Comment: I used the latest stable version. Meanwhile, I switched to dev-master - this version works correctly! and its looking better.

Comment: @eldad87 I am on "nelmio/api-doc-bundle": "^2.13", maybe that is the problem.